# Using Automator to create new folder and copy

Tags: automator

I've dug around trying to find a solution that does the following, but haven't had much luck:

So far what I've been able to make work is to have finder select specific files in my documents folder and then copy them to a location.  This works perfectly, tho I'd like to preempt this with a dialogue box that asks for a new folder name, then copies the files the this folder.

Create an application that with one click will:

1. open prompt asking for client name
2. copy a saved file structure/files into this new folder.

Would really appreciate any help possible.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please [edit] your question with what you have done so the community can see what **not** to suggest.

Comment: Also, where would the saved file structure/files come from?